# How to use a plugin in a vi-mapping?

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I'm using Tim Pope's [vim-commentary](https://github.com/tpope/vim-commentary) plugin, loaded via pathogen.

Now I want `<leader>yyp` to copy a line of code and comment out the original. I can do this with the command `yypkgccj` in normal mode (`gcc`is vim-commentary's default to comment out the current line) so I tried this mapping in my .vimrc:

```
nnoremap <leader>yyp yypkgccj
```

Does not work. However, this

```
nnoremap <leader>yyp yypk:normal gcc<cr>j
```

works.

This behaviour is the same with vim on OSX and Linux as well as mvim on OSX and gvim on Linux. Does anybody have an idea why I have to use the `:normal` command in my mapping?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 4):

if `gcc` is mapped, you want to reuse it in your new mapping, in this case, you could try: (without `nore`)

```
nmap <leader>yyp yypkgccj
```

Comment: I thought so too, but that is exactly the command which does not work (it makes no difference whether I define it with nmap or nnoremap).